# How to ensure that the index within and array contains only valid input?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I am trying to one hot encode an array and this problem is showing up. Whenever I try to execute the code it says that there is an index error. I am coding in google colaboratory.

I have tried using double square brackets to solve the problem, but still no solution

```
def read_dataset():
    df = pd.read_csv("sonar.all-data.csv")
    x = df[df.columns[0:60]].values
    y = df[df.columns[60]]
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(y)
    y = oneHotEncode(y)
    return(x, y)

def oneHotEncode(labels):
    n_labels = len(labels)
    n_unique_labels = len(np.unique(labels))
    oneHE = np.zeros((n_labels, n_unique_labels))
    oneHE[np.arange(n_labels), labels] = 1
    return oneHE
```

the expected output is an array x with all the independent variable and y with all the dependent variable that is one hot encoded. But the following error message is being shown:

```
IndexError Traceback
oneHE[np.arange(n_labels), labels] = 1 

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),    numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Why did you try double square brackets?  where?  What does that have to do with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead loop over the range(s) you want. Nested lists are referenced with `List[x][y]`, not `List[x,y]`.

The index you're saying should be equal to one is `np.arange(n_labels), labels`. Is that what you're intending or did you forget to put them as parameters to a function?

What you're doing right now is equivalent to

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a[np.arange(5), [1,2,3,4,5]] = 1
```

However the expression `np.arange(5), [1,2,3,4,5]` evaluates to `(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, so the index you're trying to use is a tuple of an array and a list.

Comment: What does that have to do with the error message?  I don't see a nested list in the OP code.  `oneHE` is created with a `np.zeros` call.  Using this index on a list produces a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

in the future, it would be beneficial to include your imports for added clarity.

I did this:

```
x = df[df.columns[0:max(df.__len__(), 60)]].values
y = df[df.columns[0:max(df.__len__(), 60)]]
```

Using `__len__` should stop you from having index issues. I am not sure what size your csv file is but having 60 as the max arg may or may not be neccesarry.

Comment: The error does not occur in the dataframe indexing, and doesn't say anything about out of bounds values.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error with:

```
In [1]: labels = ['one','two']                                                                               
In [2]: arr = np.zeros((2,2))                                                                                
In [3]: arr[np.arange(2), labels]                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-957dfbe132f5> in <module>
----> 1 arr[np.arange(2), labels]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

My guess is that your `labels` list or array is strings.

Indexing works if I provide an integer array (or list) in the right range:

```
In [5]: arr[np.arange(2), [0,1]]                                                                             
Out[5]: array([0., 0.])
```

Generally we don't test indices before hand for validity.  Instead we use them and learn from the errors.  This error message enumerates the valid types of indices for numpy arrays.  Study the numpy docs if you want more details.